# What causes TypeError: undefined is not a function?

Tags: jquery

All,
I've got some code that I'm trying to debug and I used the following bit of code in my JS console:

```
clickEvents = $('ul.breadcrumb[data-allownextonly]').data("events").click;
jQuery.each(clickEvents, function(key, value) {
    console.log(value.handler);
})
```

When I execute this I get the error:
TypeError: undefined is not a function

My question is what causes this to happen? From most of the things I read it deals with the fact that jQuery isn't loaded properly or there is a conflict between two scripts. jQuery is loading properly because I have other objects on my page that jQuery is working fine on. I'm using Wordpress so there is already no conflict.

In my console I changed my JS debugging to something like this:

```
 clickEvents = jQuery('ul.breadcrumb[data-allownextonly]').data("events").click;
jQuery.each(clickEvents, function(key, value) {
    console.log(value.handler);
})
```

When I execute this I get the following error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined

Can anyone let me know what other reasons I would be getting these errors? If I have a conflicting script or something along those lines, how can I find out where the conflict is?

Thanks!

Comment: will you please check what are you getting with `jQuery('ul.breadcrumb[data-allownextonly]').data("events")`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the jQuery API, the `.data( key )` method returns undefined if the matched element doesn't have any data matching the key. Have a look at its usage http://api.jquery.com/data/. It only operates on the first element in the matched set in any case, so you cant use it to get an array of click event handlers. As is, it is saying that the first matched element has no data attribute "events". Once you get the data that is attached, do

```
var clickEvents = [];
$( selector ).data( key ).each( function() { 
    clickEvents.push( $(this).click );
});
```

to collect the click events.

Answer (score 0):

You get that error when you try to execute a function that is uninitialized or improperly initialized.

Comment: No I did not mean to not have parentheses on the click, someone was helping me debug and provided that function to try and determine what my script was calling

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that `jQuery('ul.breadcrumb[data-allownextonly]').data("events")` is `undefined`, so any dereferencing on that raises an error.

Btw, changing `$` to `jQuery` won't change much in your code. If jQuery wasn't loaded, it would give a different error.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I don't understand why it wouldn't be loaded correctly since other jQuery objects work. This is weird since when I click on that jQuery breadcrumb nothing happens.

Comment: @user1048676 well, did you inspect the result of `.data('events')`?

Comment: It just says undefined so there is nothing to inspect. I'm a newbie to debugging

Comment: @user1048676 right, so you'd have to check the code / html that adds data to that element (either using `$().data()` or `data-events="whatever"`)

Comment: I'm using a theme and it's weird, when I run the exact same code that I posted above I get the following results: function () {
var opts = $this.data('wl_Breadcrumb') || opts;
//if disabled stop
if (opts.disabled) return false;
var _this = $(this);
//if not allownextonly or data is current+1 or current-x
if (!opts.allownextonly || _this.data('id') - $this.find('a.active').data('id') <= 1) {
//activate and trigger callback
$.fn.wl_Breadcrumb.methods.activate.call($this[0], _this);
opts.onChange.call($this[0], _this, _this.data('id'));
}
return false;
}